# Vega shows SQL injection vulnerablity but sqlmap says no

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, sqlmap

I'm pen testing an application. The URL is basically `app.php?app=appname`. If `app` exists it gives correct output, but if it doesn't exist we get a internal server error 500.

Vega detects it as a SQL injection vulnerability, but when I test it with sqlmap it cannot find injection in this url. Vega shows the URL `app.php?app=appname'%20AND%201=2%20--%20`, but it also gives the same internal error.

In this case is it really a SQL injection vulnerability? Can I force sqlmap to use this URL as a help?

Answer (score 2):

If the application is querying a database for appname, then most likely you have a SQL injection. To test the url with sqlmap run the command:

```
sqlmap -u "app.php?app=appname" -p "app"
```

[Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is a quick cheat sheet to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that their could be some blind (time-based) SQL injection vulnerabilities present, you may not have "gone deep enough" with SQLMap. By default, SQLMap does not attempt *all* SQLi methods. You can try specifying the risk level (2):

> **Risk**
>
> Option: *--risk*
>
> This option requires an argument which specifies the risk of tests to
>   perform. There are four risk values. The default value is 1 which is
>   innocuous for the majority of SQL injection points. **Risk value 2 adds
>   to the default level the tests for heavy query time-based SQL
>   injections** and value 3 adds also OR-based SQL injection tests.

**Or** Perform a simple time-based test like this:

> **Seconds to delay the DBMS response for time-based blind SQL injection**
>
> Option: *--time-sec*
>
> It is possible to set the seconds to delay the response when testing
>   for time-based blind SQL injection, by providing the --time-sec option
>   followed by an integer. By default it's value is set to 5 seconds.

[SQLMap Help](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)